# Python HTTP request failing with zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Tags: python, locust

I am trying to make a HTTP call here using fasthttp library in python. While running the get request as in below example it's giving me error shown in stacktrace. Can someone please help on this how I can handle this error?

Code used to make HTTP Request. This is responding with a zip file.

```
with self.client.get(url,headers = headers, catch_response=True) as response:
   if response.status_code == 200:
      response.success()
   else:
      response.failure()
```

Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 347, in run
    self.execute_next_task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 372, in execute_next_task
    self.execute_task(self._task_queue.pop(0))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/user/task.py", line 493, in execute_task
    task(self.user)
  File "/Users/preritjain/PycharmProjects/performance-locust/tests/test_downloads.py", line 34, in get_test_downloads
    with self.client.get(url,headers = headers, catch_response=True) as response:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/contrib/fasthttp.py", line 262, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/contrib/fasthttp.py", line 233, in request
    request_meta["response_length"] = len(response.content or "")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventhttpclient/useragent.py", line 203, in content
    self._cached_content = self._content()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/locust/contrib/fasthttp.py", line 433, in _content
    return super()._content()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventhttpclient/useragent.py", line 214, in _content
    ret = self.unzipped(gzip=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/geventhttpclient/useragent.py", line 185, in unzipped
    return zlib.decompress(bodystr, 16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Comment: Does it work using HttpUser/python-requests? Do you have latest geventhttpclient installed?

Comment: Yes, it works with HttpUser & python request both

Comment: Could be an issue with geventhttpclient then. You could try downgrading it to 1.x. Or wait until 2.1 which should be out very soon: https://github.com/geventhttpclient/geventhttpclient/pull/169

Comment: There has been a minor update (2.0.3, 2.1 will have to wait). Should be out any minute now. Might not help, but worth trying (pip install geventhttpclient==2.0.3)

Comment: Sure, i will try downgrading the version for now until we have a new version.